# Occasionally 401 Unauthorized Google Cloud Message

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, unauthorized

While using Google Cloud Message API I **occasionally** get 401 Unauthorized status. So, sometimes my push notifications are send and sometimes not, without changing anything in the API request.

I use curl request with server key.

I tried to specify IPs list and set it to "Any IP allowed".

I already tried to create new server keys and projects, as some people here tell it helps them in similar situation. Sadly, it not helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar problem with other Google Cloud APIs and I suspect it's related to your authentication being expired. Make sure to refresh any tokens you are using.